# Unknown output unicode in python 2

Tags: python, netbeans, unicode, python-2.7, netbeans-7.2

I tried to implement [this code](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/AWNDatabaseManagement.py.gz) from [NLP UPC research group](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/web/index.php?option=com_contenttask=view&id=65) to retrieve synonyms for some entered words.
when I ran the testing method

```
def test():
    "tests some functions"
    a=wn.get_words(True)
    print  'length of a: ', len(a)
    print 'a[0]: ', a[0].tostring().decode('utf-8')
```

the output is unknowing encoding

```
length of a:  16043
a[0]:  �����
```

in the same code the Unicode is already declared as

```
def _encode(data):
    return data.encode('utf8')
```

and the platform that I used (net beans 7.2.1)is configured to support utf-8 encoding

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `repr(a[0].tostring())` instead of `a[0].tostring().decode('utf-8')` and see what gets returned.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but still have the same problem :( . the output is like this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AWN.py", line 402, in test
    print 'a[0]: ', repr(a[0].tostring())
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'tostring'

Answer (score 1):

If you already configured your setup to handle UTF-8, you do not need to decode your string to a Unicode object. What will happen then is that Python uses the current encoding detected for `sys.stdout`.

Try *not* decoding:

```
print 'a[0]: ', a[0].tostring()
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answers. I used this command instead and it's worked with me

```
print 'a[0]: ', a[0].encode('utf-8')
```